# Usage of external JS objects inside a jQuery routine

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, coffeescript

I created some Javascript objects using CoffeScript. One of these objects is the experiment object:

```js
class Experiment
  @clock
  @events

  constructor: (@params) -> 
    @events = new EventsTable
    @clock = 0        

  run: ->
    setInterval ->
      perform_routine
    , 1000

  perform_routine: ->
    events = @events.get(@clock)    

    for event in events
      if event['action'] == 'start'
        console.log('an event starts.')
      else
        console.log('an event has been finished.')

    console.log(@clock)
    @clock++
```

Every time that the user clicks on some button, an experiment must be created. Considering this, I implemented a jQuery trigger:

```js
  $ ->
    $('#start-simulation').click (event) ->
      event.preventDefault();

      params = {}

      $('#simulation-parameters').find('input').each ->
        params[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();

      simulation = new Experiment params
      simulation.run();
```

The problem is that I always get an **Uncaught ReferenceError: Experiment is not defined**

Due to some research, I also tried to define the class names with an @, but doing this, I got lots of errors using the methods inside of the class.

This behaviour seems completely unnatural to me, given that I'm importing all the necessary files in the correct order (first experiments and them the one with the jQuery functions), but this is probably due to my lack of experience with javascript.

Do you know what is the proper way to use a JS external object inside of jQuery?

Comment: Is that your real CoffeeScript `Experiment`? I ask because it doesn't make a lot of sense: `create_cells` does not call a method or function, same for `perform_routine` and `@` wouldn't even be what you're expecting inside a `setInterval` callback, ... And then you'd have the scope wrapper in the generated JavaScript to contend with.

Comment: It is, partially. The create_cells and create_calls were defined but not shown. Thanks for your tips, I'm gonna take a look on it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several problems:

1. CoffeeScript wraps your code in an SIF to prevent scope creep. This:

   ```
   class C
   ```

   becomes something like this:

   ```
   (function() {
       var C = // the JavaScript definition of C ...
   }).call(this);
   ```

   The SIF wrapper is to prevent anything in your CoffeeScript from accidentally polluting the global namespace. In your case, the `Experiment` JavaScript variable is hidden inside a function so it won't be visible inside any other CoffeeScript files.

   The usual browser solution is to say `class @Experiment` to make your class a property of the global object. A better solution is to manually namespace things; somewhere before anything else happens you want to say:

   ```
   window.app = { } # where "app" is some namespace unique to your application
   ```

   and then you can say `class app.Experiment` and `new app.Experiment`.
2. At the `class` level, `@` is the class itself. That means that this:

   ```
   class Experiment
     @clock
     @events
   ```

   declares two class properties (`Experiment.clock` and `Experiment.events`) but neglects to give them a value. These properties are **not** in the prototype, they're right on the class function itself. You probably want to say:

   ```
   class Experiment
     clock: undefined
     events: undefined
   ```

   if your intent is to tell the outside world that `Experiment` instances have `clock` and `events` properties.
3. In CoffeeScript, saying `f` does not call the function `f`, it just gives you a reference to `f` without bothering to store it anywhere. To call a function without arguments, you say `f()`. Also, if you want to call a method, you need to supply the receiver. In your case, your `constructor` should be more like this:

   ```
   constructor: (@params) -> 
     @events = new EventsTable
     @clock = 0
     @create_cells()
     @create_calls()
   ```
4. Your `run` method suffers from the same "missing receiver and missing function-calling parentheses" problems as your `constructor`. Also, when `setInterval` calls its callback, it doesn't supply any particular `@` (AKA `this`) so you'll need a bound function:

   ```
   run: -> setInterval (=> @perform_routine()), 1000
   # or
   run: -> setInterval @perform_routine.bind(@), 1000
   # or:
   perform_routine: => ...
   run: -> setInterval @perform_routine, 1000
   ```

   You might want to store the [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval) return value somewhere too, that way you can call [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.clearInterval) to stop it:

   ```
   run: ->
     @interval = setInterval ...
   stop: ->
     clearInterval(@interval) if(@interval)
     @interval = undefined
   ```

You probably have similar problems in the rest of your `Experiment`.

Comment: This community is awesome 'cause of users like you. I would never suspect that I was making so many mistakes. Implementing your suggestions, everything is working as expected.

Thanks for sharing part of your knowledge in a so comprehensible way!